# jQuery on element value equals x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a jQuery script which uses `jquery-circle-progress` ( a third party plugin) to count up to a certain number. For example, say the variable `rand` holds this number. The script then finds a specified element, and then counts up from zero to this number.

I would like to detect when the animation finishes. I have considered waiting until the element.val == `rand` , and then execute another function.

```
$('#circle').circleProgress({
            value: (rand/100) }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress) {
            $(this).find('.element').html(parseInt( 100 * progress * rand/100));
            });
```

Then I was thinking of doing something like

on element.val == `rand` 
do someFunction()

So it waits for element.val to equal `rand` and then execute a function.
Or is there an easier way to detect animation completion?

I know this is specific, TIA.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the plugin? Often, you can pass in a function which will be called when the animation completes.

Comment: Yep, `circle-animation-end` function(event). How would i act upon this?

Comment: I don't know what more to explain. Pass a function to that option, and it will run when the animation ends.

Comment: What would I select, the circle div? Something like `$('#circle').on('circle-animation-end', myFunction(event) { do something });` Am i using the right selector? If you want to drop it as a correct answer please do so i can mark it.

Comment: The JS code linked to on the [examples page](http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/) should be able to answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress shows a `circle-animation-end` event. I'm not familiar with this plugin but I would expect that you could hook into this event after you call `$('#circle').circleProgress()` with something like:

```
$('#circle').on('circle-animation-end', function(){
    alert('animation complete');
});
```